# Xcode can't find my static library!

Tags: iphone, ios, static-libraries

Here is the linker error:

i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: /Users/william/Documents/SettingsLibrary/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSettingsLibrary.a: No such file or directory
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

A couple of weird things, which may be clues to what is going on:

1)  In my "library search paths", I have included the recursive path to the library project:
../SettingsLibrary/**

However, SettingsLibrary builds itself to SettingsLibrary/build/Debug/iphoneos/libSettingsLibrary.a
Meanwhile, based on the error message, the linker appears to be looking in:
SettingsLibrary/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSettingsLibrary.a

2)  I have included the library project in my main project.  When I right click under groups and files, there is an option to include the libSettingsLibrary.a file in my target or not.  In at least one other library-using project I have looked at, that checkbox is not there for the .a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to say what the problem is with your project. Can you check the following in the *Groups & File* view of the main project:

- Does the static library project (SettingsLibrary.xcodeproj) appear as a node below your app (the very first node)?
- Does the library file (libSettingsLibrary.a) appear just below?
- Does the static library (*SettingsLibrary (from SettingsLibrary.xcodeproj)* ) appear as a node below the main target (at *Targets / YourApp*)?
- Does the library file (libSettingsLibrary.a) appear just below the node *Link Binary With Libraries* (in the targets section)?

If not, what's missing?

Furthermore, my *Library Search Path* is empty. If I look at the command line for the linker, it explicitly contains the full path to the static library (*SettingsLibrary/build/Debug/iphoneos/libSettingsLibrary.a* in your case).

And the checkbox you mention (right-clicking on the static library project within *Groups & Files*): I have it as well, but it's not checked.

Comment: I was missing the static library as a node below the main target, thanks.  Everything links now.

Comment: One thing is missing for newer Xcode versions. In Section "Swift Compiler - Search paths", in the filed "Import Paths", you should put the same path from "Library Search Path".