# Can't use Swift classes inside Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, static-libraries

I try to integrate `Swift` code in my app.My app is written in `Objective-C` and I added a `Swift` class. I've done everything described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77). But my problem is that `Xcode` haven't created the `-Swift.h` file, only the bridging headers. So I created it, but it's actually empty.
I can use all my ObjC classes in Swift, but I can't do it vice versa. I marked my swift class with `@objc` but it didn't help. What can I do now?

EDIT: Apple says:" When you import Swift code into Objective-C, you rely on an `Xcode-generated` header file to expose those files to Objective-C. [...] The name of this header is your product module name followed by adding “-Swift.h”. "

Now when I want to import that File, it gives an error:

```
    //MainMenu.m

    #import "myProjectModule-Swift.h" //Error: 'myProjectModule-Swift.h' file not found

    @implementation MainMenu
```

Here is my FBManager.swift file:

```
@objc class FBManager: NSObject {

    var descr = "FBManager class"

    init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func desc(){
        println(descr)
    }

    func getSharedGameState() -> GameState{
        return GameState.sharedGameState() //OK! GameState is written in Objective-C and no error here
    }
}
```

Comment: `YourProjectName-Swift.h` should be a magical header file that Xcode automagically creates for you during compilation (you won't actually see it in the project browser). Try deleting the one you created, and add `#import YourProjectName-Swift.h` to the files in which you want to use the Swift classes.

Comment: Show the definition of your `Swift` class and how you are accessing it from `Objective-C`.

Comment: @vacawama I added some code. I hope it helps. From what I see, I think that the `-Swift.h` file is not created, so I can't include it.

Comment: Is your app that you are building called `myProjectModule`?  The `-Swift.h` file should begin with your app name.  Do you have a file ending in `-Bridging-Header.h`?  You should.  If so, the first part of that file is your project name.  Combine the first part of that filename with `-Swift.h` and that is what you should be including.

Comment: I have this successfully working in my project, and yet there is no actual file ending in `-Swift.h` to be found on my Mac, and yet I can include it.  So don't get hung up looking for such a file.  Just make sure you are naming it correctly.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite - Thanks, biggest help to me here was finding out you could not see the Product-Swift.h file in the project browser!  Was looking and looking...

Comment: @vacawama Note that you can see the contents after you add the import statement to an Objective-C file by Command-Clicking on the import as if you were visiting any other header file.

Comment: I had to use `#import <MyProjectName/MyProjectName-Swift.h>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import Swift code to Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c)

Answer (score 541):

I spent about 4 hours trying to enable `Swift` in my `Xcode` Objective-C based project. My `myproject-Swift.h` file was created successfully, but my `Xcode` didn't see my `Swift-classes`. So, I decided to create a new `Xcode` Objc-based project and finally, I found the right answer! Hope this post will help someone :-)

### Step by step Swift integration for Xcode Objc-based project:

1. Create new `*.swift` file (in Xcode) or add it by using Finder.
2. Create an `Objective-C bridging header` when Xcode asks you about that.
3. Implement your Swift class:

   ```
   import Foundation

   // use @objc or @objcMembers annotation if necessary
   class Foo {
       //..
   }
   ```
4. Open Build Settings and check these parameters:

   - **Defines Module :** `YES`

     > Copy & Paste parameter name in a search bar
   - **Product Module Name :** `myproject`

     > Make sure that your Product Module Name doesn't contain any special characters
   - **Install Objective-C Compatibility Header :** `YES`

     > Once you've added `*.swift` file to the project this property will appear in Build Settings
   - **Objective-C Generated Interface Header :** `myproject-Swift.h`

     > This header is auto-generated by Xcode
   - **Objective-C Bridging Header :** `$(SRCROOT)/myproject-Bridging-Header.h`
5. Import Swift interface header in your *.m file.

   ```
   #import "myproject-Swift.h"
   ```

   > Don't pay attention to errors and warnings.
6. Clean and rebuild your Xcode project.
7. Profit!

Comment: Has anyone seen mention of the configuration required (at least for me) in the documentation at:

 https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77

 in step 4 above? If it is I missed it. Thanks @sig.

Comment: In my case the _swift.h file is not even created in my DerivedSources folder. Of course I cannot compile regularly as the fact the swift class is not found produces errors. Should I remove the swift classes and the calls to them, rebuild and then readd the file and calls again?

Comment: Ok, I did remove the references to the swift files but not the files and I think came closer to the problem. Now the compiler complaints that: the SDK 'iPhoneOS7.1.sdk' does not support Swift, whatever that may mean. I searched on the net for the full sentence but strangely found nothing. Any hint?

Comment: My problem was much simpler - I couldn't find the file `"myproject-Swift.h"` so  it seems to me like it's not working. Apparently, this file is not visible in the project navigator.

Comment: @Asaf Actually, yes, this file is auto-genereting by Xcode and locating in your project build-path. So, you can find this file manually in Finder/Console or open it directly in Xcode by using Cmd+LeftClick on `#import "myproject-Swift.h"`.

Comment: As for me #5 was enough to fix problem!!

Comment: Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : YES. I don't have this in my Build Settings. And I don't even have any swift compiler available in my Build Settings. You said you created the Obj-c based project but this solutions does not work for me.

Comment: @SnowWolf You sure that you chose right target? Try to use search in Build Settings and paste those sentences.

Comment: I have two targets in my project. So product names are different. #import "myproject-Swift.h" needs to be edited when I build target. Like #import "myproject1-Swift.h" and #import "myproject2-Swift.h". Can I avoid this edit work with some generic tag.

Comment: Embedded content contains swift code can be NO. Defines Modules can be NO. If your class subclasses an Objective-C class, you definitely do NOT need the @objc tag.

Comment: With your those 4 hours, you saved hundred of our hours,
Thanks a lot :)
Saved in my Favorite ;)

Comment: If nothing helps - check `@import swiftClassName;` (swiftClassName.swift)

Comment: Refer this article.It expains nicely:http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-use-swift-classes-in-objective-c/

Comment: After 2 hours of struggle, I found my mistake: once I created my .swift file, xcode didn't generate a -Swift.h file for me (it did, but the file is not visible in the project anyhow), so I created it by myself x_x. Guys, it's a trap! Never create -Swift.h file by hand! Xcode will include this file from only-god-knows-where by itself.

Comment: I got my project running and everything is working fine. Only thing is without adding prefix "@objc" the app is running properly. So is it really required to add this prefix to classes?

Comment: Argh, forgetting to clean the project (6) was my bane.

Comment: Please I can't find Install Objective-C Compatibility Header. I use Xcode 8

Comment: @Llg In Xcode 8.2.1 open Build Settings tab and paste "Install Objective-C Compatibility Header" in the Search field.

Comment: Re. special characters in the module/project name, my problem was a hyphen in the project name (beyond my control). The Swift interface header replaced the hyphen with an underscore, which I hadn't realised.

Comment: I only did #5 #import "myproject-Swift.h" and it solved the problem. I didn't do anything else.

Comment: Just didn't work for me. All I did was adding one .swift file to a project via Finder d'n'd to Xode, accepted the Bridging Header creation, followed steps, and I still get the error that '-Swift.h' import cannot be found.

Comment: Did everything as outlined. Still not working. Trying to add Charts for iOS Swift project to my Objective-C project and getting error module-Swift.h not found.

Comment: @mixtly87 Build your project and error will disappear

Comment: @Dalmazio Use Cocoapods. Otherwise check the Usage section in Readme file inside repository and use `@import Charts`.

Comment: So something strange. It seems that Xcode was indexing, and while indexing, compiling gave the error that it can't find the <Charts/Charts.h> Swift framework headers for #import'ing into Objective-C source. Maybe I was too impatient. After starting over, cleaned all changes and letting it finish index, it worked. Anyway, thanks @sig for the heads up.

Comment: Didn't work for me until I changed the import directive from ```#import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"```  to ```#import <YourProjectName-Swift.h>```.

Comment: Changing  Product Name  in Build Setting to My project name with Defines Module set to YES worked for me !!!!

Comment: xcode doesn't ask me about `Create an Objective-C bridging header when Xcode ask you about that` when I create swift class!

Comment: @user924 I checked that this message is displayed on `Xcode 9.3`. I can only suggest you to add file manually: `project/project-Bridging-Header.h`. And carefully follow the instructions in paragraph 4.

Comment: For me, I follow the steps above, and i can see the generated `product-Swift.h` files in build source, but It still can not find my Swift class in Object C. Finally it proved that you need to make sure the swift class in step #3 inherits `NSObject`.

Answer (score 69):

Don't create the header file yourself. Delete the one you created.

Make sure your Swift classes are tagged with `@objc` or inherit from a class that derives (directly or indirectly) from `NSObject`.

Xcode won't generate the file if you have any compiler errors in your project - make sure your project builds cleanly.

Comment: being build-able was the key for me. Couldn't build because it couldn't find my -swift.h file, but it couldn't find my -swift.h file because it couldn't build :/

Comment: @anders while trapped in that cycle, you can use `find ~/library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ -name "*-Swift.h"|xargs basename|sort -u` to see if the file was created with an unexpected name like it was for me. :)

Comment: Make sure, that ```*-Bridging-Header.h``` file is also created, not only ```*-Swift.h``` file. It is critical to have it, even if it is empty. If it is not created, create it yourself and add it to the project build settings for ```Objective-C Bridging Header``` value.

Answer (score 40):

Allow Xcode to do its work, do not add/create Swift header manually. Just add @objc before your Swift class ex.

```
@objc class YourSwiftClassName: UIViewController
```

In your project setting search for below flags and change it to YES (Both Project and Target)

```
Defines Module : YES
Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries : YES
Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : YES
```

Then clean the project and build once, after build succeed (it should probably) import below header file in your objective-c class .m file

```
#import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"
```

Boooom!

Comment: Thanks, this was fantastically simple and resolved my problem.

Comment: I see none of these options in Build Settings (Xcode 7.3.1). What should I do?

Comment: ^ Had to switch from `Basic` to `All` in the top bar.

Comment: ``Embedded Content Contains Swift`` was changed to ``Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries`` with Xcode 8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792650/embedded-content-contains-swift-code-with-xcode-8-beta

Comment: @WilliamGrand Thanks for the suggestion, updated the answer.

Comment: Please I can't find Install Objective-C Compatibility Header. I use Xcode 8

Comment: @Llg select *All* from top while searching Install Objective-C Compatibility Header

Comment: `Only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc`

Comment: do I need all flags, any explanation about each flag?

Answer (score 30):

Also probably helpful for those of you with a **Framework target**:

The **import statement** of the auto-generated header file looks **a bit different** from app targets. In addition to the other things mentioned in other answers use

```
#import <ProductName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h>
```

instead of

```
#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"
```

as per Apples documentation on [Mix & Match](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID130) for framework targets.

Comment: @dinesharjani Glad I could help! :)

Comment: What about bundle targets?

Answer (score 16):

**Details:** Objective-C project with Swift 3 code in Xcode 8.1

**Tasks:**

1. Use swift enum in objective-c class
2. Use objective-c enum in swift class

### FULL SAMPLE

### 1. Objective-C class which use Swift enum

> ObjcClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ObjcEnum) {
    ObjcEnumValue1,
    ObjcEnumValue2,
    ObjcEnumValue3
};

@interface ObjcClass : NSObject

+ (void) PrintEnumValues;

@end
```

> ObjcClass.m

```
#import "ObjcClass.h"
#import "SwiftCode.h"

@implementation ObjcClass

+ (void) PrintEnumValues {
    [self PrintEnumValue:SwiftEnumValue1];
    [self PrintEnumValue:SwiftEnumValue2];
    [self PrintEnumValue:SwiftEnumValue3];
}

+ (void) PrintEnumValue:(SwiftEnum) value {
    switch (value) {
        case SwiftEnumValue1:
            NSLog(@"-- SwiftEnum: SwiftEnumValue1");
            break;
            
        case SwiftEnumValue2:
        case SwiftEnumValue3:
            NSLog(@"-- SwiftEnum: long value = %ld", (long)value);
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

### Detect Swift code in Objective-C code

In my sample I use SwiftCode.h to detect Swift code in Objective-C. This file generate automatically (I did not create a physical copy of this header file in a project), and you can only set name of this file:

[image]

> [image]
>
> If the compiler can not find your header file Swift code, try to compile the project.

### 2. Swift class which use Objective-C  enum

```
import Foundation

@objc
enum SwiftEnum: Int {
    case Value1, Value2, Value3
}

@objc
class SwiftClass: NSObject {
    
    class func PrintEnumValues() {
        PrintEnumValue(.Value1)
        PrintEnumValue(.Value2)
        PrintEnumValue(.Value3)
    }
    
    class func PrintEnumValue(value: ObjcEnum) {
        switch value {
        case .Value1, .Value2:
            NSLog("-- ObjcEnum: int value = \(value.rawValue)")
            
        case .Value3:
            NSLog("-- ObjcEnum: Value3")
            break
        }
        
    }
}
```

### Detect Objective-C code in Swift code

You need to create bridging header file. When you add Swift file in Objective-C project, or Objective-C file in swift project Xcode will suggest you to create  bridging header.

[image]

**You can change bridging header file name here:**

[image]

> Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "ObjcClass.h"
```

### Usage

```
#import "SwiftCode.h"
...
[ObjcClass PrintEnumValues];
[SwiftClass PrintEnumValues];
[SwiftClass PrintEnumValue:ObjcEnumValue3];
```

### Result

[image]

---

### MORE SAMPLES

> **Full integration steps Objective-c and Swift described above**. Now I will write some other code examples.

### 3. Call Swift class from Objective-c code

> Swift class

```
import Foundation

@objc
class SwiftClass:NSObject {
    
    private var _stringValue: String
    var stringValue: String {
        get {
            print("SwiftClass get stringValue")
            return _stringValue
        }
        set {
            print("SwiftClass set stringValue = \(newValue)")
            _stringValue = newValue
        }
    }
    
    init (stringValue: String) {
        print("SwiftClass init(String)")
        _stringValue = stringValue
    }
    
    func printValue() {
        print("SwiftClass printValue()")
        print("stringValue = \(_stringValue)")
    }
    
}
```

> Objective-C code (calling code)

```
SwiftClass *obj = [[SwiftClass alloc] initWithStringValue: @"Hello World!"];
[obj printValue];
NSString * str = obj.stringValue;
obj.stringValue = @"HeLLo wOrLd!!!";
```

**Result**

[image]

### 4. Call Objective-c class from Swift code

> Objective-C class (ObjcClass.h)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ObjcClass : NSObject
@property NSString* stringValue;
- (instancetype) initWithStringValue:(NSString*)stringValue;
- (void) printValue;
@end
```

> ObjcClass.m

```
#import "ObjcClass.h"

@interface ObjcClass()

@property NSString* strValue;

@end

@implementation ObjcClass

- (instancetype) initWithStringValue:(NSString*)stringValue {
    NSLog(@"ObjcClass initWithStringValue");
    _strValue = stringValue;
    return self;
}

- (void) printValue {
    NSLog(@"ObjcClass printValue");
    NSLog(@"stringValue = %@", _strValue);
}

- (NSString*) stringValue {
    NSLog(@"ObjcClass get stringValue");
    return _strValue;
}

- (void) setStringValue:(NSString*)newValue {
    NSLog(@"ObjcClass set stringValue = %@", newValue);
    _strValue = newValue;
}

@end
```

> Swift code (calling code)

```
if let obj = ObjcClass(stringValue:  "Hello World!") {
    obj.printValue()
    let str = obj.stringValue;
    obj.stringValue = "HeLLo wOrLd!!!";
}
```

**Result**

[image]

### 5. Use Swift extension in Objective-c code

> Swift extension

```
extension UIView {
    static func swiftExtensionFunc() {
        NSLog("UIView swiftExtensionFunc")
    }
}
```

> Objective-C code (calling code)

```
[UIView swiftExtensionFunc];
```

### 6. Use Objective-c extension in swift code

> Objective-C extension (UIViewExtension.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (ObjcAdditions)
+ (void)objcExtensionFunc;
@end
```

> UIViewExtension.m

```
@implementation UIView (ObjcAdditions)
+ (void)objcExtensionFunc {
    NSLog(@"UIView objcExtensionFunc");
}
@end
```

> Swift code (calling code)

```
UIView.objcExtensionFunc()
```

Comment: These samples are really helpful, thank you! And as for Swift 4+, we need to add `@objcMembers` in front of the class. Because `@objc` inference have been reduced in Swift 4 for optimization purpose. For instance, a property within an  NSObject-derived class,  will no longer infer @objc by default (as it did in Swift 3). I got this intel from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656756/4394850).

Answer (score 14):

Make sure your project defines a module and you have given a name to the module. Then rebuild, and Xcode will create the `-Swift.h` header file and you will be able to import.

You can set module definition and module name in your project settings.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and it turned out special symbols in the module name are replaced by xcode  (in my case dashes ended up being underscores). In project settings check "module name" to find the module name for your project. After that either use `ModuleName-Swift.h` or rename the module in settings.

Comment: I'm a moron. I was adding the Class name and then appending "-Swift". Turns out it's the "module" name. +1 for making me realize this.

Comment: Another moron here who thought it was the class name!

Answer (score 9):

The file is created automatically (talking about Xcode 6.3.2 here). But you won't see it, since it's in your Derived Data folder. After marking your swift class with `@objc`, compile, then search for `Swift.h` in your Derived Data folder. You should find the Swift header there.

I had the problem, that Xcode renamed my `my-Project-Swift.h` to `my_Project-Swift.h` Xcode doesn't like
`"." "-"` etc. symbols. With the method above you can find the filename and import it to a Objective-C class.

Comment: This too solved my problem. In my .m file i import the file like this `#import "my_project-Swift.h"`  and my actual project name is `my-project`

Comment: Attention- not just "." "-" also spaces  :(

Answer (score 9):

For Swift 5:

1. Add the `@objc` keyword to your class and methods
2. Add `public` keyword to your class and methods
3. Let your class inherit from `NSObject`
4. Build Project
5. Put `#import "MyProject-Swift.h"` in your Objective-C file

   ```
   @objc
   public class MyClass: NSObject {

       @objc
       public func myMethod() {

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: "Add the @objc keyword to your class and methods" - the same for Swift 4

Answer (score 8):

Just include 
  #import "myProject-Swift.h" in .m or .h file

P.S You will not find "myProject-Swift.h" in file inspector it's hidden. But it is generated by app automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, mate.

Comment: This answer helped me and saved my day. The important thing is than Xcode is generating it automatically and it's HIDDEN file. I was creating "myProject-Swift.h" myself and it was not working.

Answer (score 6):

@sig answer is one of the best, however, it did not work for me with the old project (not new!), I needed some modifications. After a lot of variations I found the recipe for me (using XCode 7.2):

1. Product Module Name : $(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)
2. Defines Module : NO
3. Embedded Content Contains Swift : NO
4. Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : YES
5. Objective-C Bridging Header : ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h

The last point (5) was crucial. I put it only on the second section (Targets field), the Project field should be left empty: [image] Otherwise, it did not generate the right "Project-Swift.h" file for me (it did not include swift methods).

Comment: also a helpful link: http://ericasadun.com/2014/08/21/swift-calling-swift-functions-from-objective-c/

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks a lot @DariusMiliauskas only got it working with your link

Comment: @DariusMiliauskasthanks a lot! the 5 point also solved issue for me in old Xcode project

Comment: `Define Modules` should be `No`??

Comment: @SunilChauhan, Yes, [it is only used for framewoks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID172).

Comment: `Defines Modules`***

Answer (score 6):

**There is two condition,**

- Use your swift file in objective c file.
- Use your objective c file in swift file.

**So, For that purpose, you have to follow this steps:**

- Add your swift file in an objective-c project or vice-versa.
- Create header(.h) file.
- Go to **Build Settings** and perform below steps with search,

  1. search for this text "brid" and set a path of your header file.
  2. "Defines Module": YES.
  3. "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" : YES.
  4. "Install Objective-C Compatibility Header" : YES.

After that, clean and rebuild your project.

## Use your swift file in objective c file.

In that case,First write "@objc" before your class in swift file.

After that ,In your objective c file, write this,

```
  #import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"
```

## Use your objective c file in swift file.

In that case, In your header file, write this,

```
  #import "YourObjective-c_FileName.h"
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, apart from these steps:

1. Product Module Name : myproject
2. Defines Module : YES
3. Embedded Content Contains Swift : YES
4. Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : YES
5. Objective-C Bridging Header : $(SRCROOT)/Sources/SwiftBridging.h

I have needed to put the class as **public** in order to create **productName-Swift.h** file:

```
import UIKit

   @objc public class TestSwift: NSObject {
       func sayHello() {
          print("Hi there!")
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered that adding a directory of swift files to a project won't work.  You need to create a group first for the directory, then add the swift files...

Comment: @<specific class>; should be defined, and then the using project will see those files.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and finally it appeared that they weren't attached to the same targets. 
The ObjC class is attached to Target1 and Target2, the Swift class is only attached to the Target1 and is not visible inside the ObjC class.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I completely overlooked this with different targets for staging and production. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: What does "attached" mean?

Comment: "attached" = "members", they should be listed as target members

Answer (score 1):

my problem was I got stuck after xcode created the bridge file but still I got error in header file name  MYPROJECTNAME-swift.h

1.I check in terminal and search for all auto created swift bridge files:

`find ~/library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ -name "*-Swift.h"|xargs basename|sort -`

you see what xcode created.

2. in my case, I had space in my project name and xcode replace this is '_'

Answer (score 1):

When you add new Swift files to the project, please, make sure that you add them to correct targets.
Please, make sure that every swift file you're going to use inherits NSObject class and annotated with @ObjCMembers
Change to YES inside the build settings under the option ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES.
Change to YES inside the build settings under the option DEFINES_MODULE.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Swift Classes in Objective-C**

If you are going to import code within an App Target (Mixing Objective-C and Swift in one project) you should use the next import line `#import "<#YourProjectName#>-Swift.h"` to expose Swift code to Objective-C code [<sup>[Mixing Swift and Objective-C code in a project]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217109/4770877)

In this post I will describe how to import Swift static library to Objective-C code

### Objective-C consumer -> Swift static library

Xcode version 10.2.1

### Create Swift static library

Follow [`Create Swift static library`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55899567/4770877) with next additions:

Expose Swift API. To use Swift's functions from Objective-C[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217057/4770877)

After building you should find a `<product_name>-Swift.h` file that should be located into `DerivedSources` [<sup>[File not found]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57540240/4770877)

### Objective-C consumer with Swift static library

`Drag and drop` the binary into the Xcode project[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216377/4770877)

`Link Library`[<sup>[Undefined symbols]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57538354/4770877) [<sup>[Link vs Embed]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216858/4770877)

```
Project editor -> select a target -> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries -> add -> Add Others... -> point to `lib<product_name>.a` file
//or
Project editor -> select a target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> add -> Add Others... -> point to `lib<product_name>.a` file
```

Add `Library Search paths`[<sup>[Library not found for]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216466/4770877) [<sup>[Recursive path]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57516845/4770877)

```
Project editor -> select a target -> Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Library Search paths -> add path to the parent of `lib<product_name>.a` file
```

Add `Header Search Paths`[<sup>[Module not found]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216466/4770877) [[Recursive path]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57516845/4770877)

```
Project editor -> select a target -> Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths -> add path to generated `<product_name>-Swift.h` file
```

Add empty `.swift file` to the Objective-C project.[<sup>[Undefined symbols]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57538354/4770877)  When Xcode ask press Create `Bridging Header`(it will create `module_name-Bridging-Header.h`) and setup a path to this file in

```
Project editor -> select a target -> Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - General -> Objective-C Bridging Header
```

Import module to the Objective-C client code[<sup>[File not found]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57540240/4770877) [<sup>[module_name]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57517400/4770877)

```
#import "module_name-Swift.h"
```

[More examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error: `myProjectModule-Swift.h` file not found", but, in my case, real reason was in wrong deployment target:
"`Swift` is unavailable on OS X earlier than 10.9; please set `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` to 10.9 or later (currently it is '10.7')"
so, when I've changed deployment target to 10.9 - project had been compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the auto-generation of the -swift.h file was not able to understand a subclass of CustomDebugStringConvertible.  I changed class to be a subclass of NSObject instead.  After that, the -swift.h file now included the class properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues in that I would add classes to my objective-c bridging header, and in those objective-c headers that were imported, they were trying to import the swift header.  It didn't like that.

So in all my objective-c classes that use swift, but are also bridged, the key was to make sure that you use forward class declarations in the headers, then import the "*-Swift.h" file in the .m file.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt have to change any settings in the build or add @obj to the class.

All I had to do was to create bridge-header which was automatically created when I created Swift classes into Objective-c project. And then I just had to do

## import "Bedtime-Swift.h" <- inside objective-c file that needed to use that swift file.

Answer (score 0):

well, after reading all the comments and trying and reading and trying again, I managed to include swift classes into my Big obj-c project.
So, thanks for all the help.
I wanted to share one tip that helped me understand the process better.
In the .m class, went to the import line of the swift target name #import "myTargetName-Swift.h"
and clicked the key:

command + mouse click -> Jump to definition
[image]

There you can see all the translation from swift to obj-c and ther you will find the various functions re-declared in obj-c.
Hope this tip will help you as much as it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

XCode 11.3.1:

<s>When I want to use an Swift inner class in a objc code, it does not compile for ther error "undefined symbol"(for bother inner class and outer class), I checked the generated "-swift.h" header and both classes are there.</s>

After trying for hours I convert the inner class to a normal class and it compiles.

I clean the project, delete the DerivedData folder and it compiles.

Comment: Did You try to add `@objc` before the declaration of the inner class?

Comment: thanks @dnnagy, checked that it is not syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use CocoaPods and the Swift class from my library couldn't be located from the Objective-C code in the example app because it's project and target were named the same as the library, so I had to remove the `Objective-C Generated Interface Name` values so they didn't conflict with the ones from the library.

Answer (score 0):

**Archiving will be successful already tested**

***How to call a swift function (that could be in a swift framework also) in objective c project or react native project***

*it will work for react-native also*
follow these steps :

> Open Build Settings and check these parameters:
> **Defines Module : YES**

> in AppDelegate.h

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class KB;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) KB *appkb;

@end
```

> in AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [self.appkb methodReceiveSwiftClass];
  [self.appkb methodEvents:event prop:properties];
}

@end
```

> KB.swift

```
import Foundation
// import framework if using a swift framework in objective c or react native native modules.
@objc public class KB:NSObject{
  
  @objc public func methodReceiveSwiftClass(){
    //write anything here....
  }

  @objc public func methodEvents(_ event: String, prop: String){
    //write anything here
     //func with params
  }

}
```

> ProjectModuleName-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Answer (score -1):

After doing everything above, I still got errors. My problem ended up being that the Swift files I needed weren't added to the bundle resources for some reason.

I fixed this by going to [MyTarget] > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources, then clicked the plus button and added the Swift files.

Comment: Copy Bundle Resources should not include source code