# Including Swift files in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm attempting to include a swift class in an objective-c project. The swift class inherits from `UIView` and looks like this:

```
class BVDTestView: UIView {
...
}
```

Note that I do not include `@objc` because the swift class inherits from `UIView`. In an objective-c implementation file, I import the umbrella swift header:

```
#import "TestApp-Swift.h"
```

I see that this file is created when I build, but I do not see any references to `BVDTestView` in it (I would think that I would). When I try to create an instance of the swift view I get the error:

```
BVDTestView *view = [BVDTestView new];
```

Use of undeclared identifier 'view'

Any thoughts? I'm on Xcode 6 beta 4.

Comment: My guess: The file "BDVTestView.swift" has not been added to the target (check the "Target Membership" checkbox in the file inspector.

Comment: Thanks for the response -- however, every swift file has the correct target checked in file inspector underneath Target Membership

Comment: Possibly stupid, but I have to ask. Did you try to build at all? I have had several problems with interoperability code being reported as errors, but when I build everything compiles normally.

Comment: Yeah it usually appears as a build error but goes away while still in the build process.

Comment: Make sure `Defines Module` is set to `YES` for your project (not only your target) and the `Project Module Name` is set to the correct name.

Comment: @Sulthan Defines Module is set to YES for both the project and target. The Project Module Name is TestApp and I'm using TestApp-Swift.h (which was created at build). Still running into the same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c

Comment: @SantaClaus - looks like a bit of a different issue that the OP was experiencing.

Comment: @bdev I thought so, but I decided to post it anyway with the hope that it might help somebody.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this recently. As of Beta 4, Swift has [access specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=5), and

> By default, all entities have `internal` access.

You need to explicitly mark the class as `public class BVDTestView ...` for it to appear in the generated header.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, when I created new Obj-C based project and want to integrate Swift code faced no problem, without specifiers like "public" it works. But one of my existing Obj-C based project when I test to add swift code I found the problem and solved it by providing "Public" access specifier in both class and function.

```
@objc public class Test: NSObject{
 @objc public func test(){
    println("test")
}
```

}