# Integrating Swift to Objective-C application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an Objective-C application where I like to integrate Swift, but I have an odd issue.

I imported `<#ProjectName#>-Swift.h` to my implementation file, where I needed the Swift Class. My Swift Class looks like this:

```
import Foundation

@objc class FileIconColor: NSObject {

    @objc func fileIconColorForSuffix(suffix: NSString) -> UIColor {
        var color:UIColor!
        //Some huge calculations
        return color
    }

    //Just for testing
    @objc func test () {
        println("Test")
    }

}
```

I am able to call the Class, but I am not able to access the functions in the class; As you can see, the `@objc` prefixes are there, on both the Class and its functions.

Do you know why this happens? I also build the project before I want to use the function, because the Swift bridging header first needs to be built, am I correct?

Oh and btw, I managed to access Objective-C code in my Swift Class. So there can't be much wrong (I manually created the Objective-C bridging header) :)

Thanks, David

Comment: Suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c?rq=1

Comment: @Caroline I didn't create the `<#ProjectName#>-Swift.h` myself. I know that It is been created by Xcode. I imported the `<#ProjectName#>-Swift.h` file and of corse replaced `<#ProjectName#>` with the name of my Project. I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: How are you creating an instance of the class and calling the functions from ObjC? What isn't working. You can't compile? Nothing happens when you run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested to see that it works for me in an old Objective C project. I'm on Xcode 6.0.1.

I did this:

1. Upgraded my old project to Xcode 6, and set Deployment Target to 7.1
2. Created a new Swift file and said yes to configuring an Objective-C bridging header.
3. Pasted your code into it. (I also had to import UIKit for UIColor to compile.)
4. In my main View controller, I put this:

At the top:

```
#import "PhotoUnzipper-Swift.h"
```

(PhotoUnzipper's the name of my project)

and in viewDidLoad:

```
FileIconColor *color = [[FileIconColor alloc]  init];
[color test];
```

It compiled, and I got "Test" printing out in the console.

***Important:*** I did **not** import the `<#ProjectName#>-Swift.h` file. Xcode takes care of that.

The first time I tried, I had problems because I had a deployment target of 4.1. (silly me.) I did not seem to be able to resolve that, but started again, and followed those steps above exactly and it worked.

Comment: Thats odd. After I restarted my Mac and deleted deviated Data eveything works fine... anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: not working.. still giving me an expected type error. cleared derived data.