# Use Swift Library in ObjC

Tags: ios

Is there a simple way to use a Swift library in ObjC? And if yes, how can I do it ?

Here the library I would like to use: https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Regift

By the way, if you guys know another way to convert video to animated gif in iOS. Thanks!

Comment: https://medium.com/swift-programming/merge-objective-c-static-library-into-swift-using-mosquitto-87ce0b6ec513

Comment: Hi @clementr Can u please tell me how did u solve this...i tried apple doc but i m missing out on something...

Comment: [Objective-C consumer -> Swift static library] - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216016/4770877

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look of Apple's document.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Referring to it,

> To import Swift code into Objective-C from the same target
>
> Import the Swift code from that target into any Objective-C .m file
> within that target using this syntax and substituting the appropriate
> name: OBJECTIVE-C
>
> ## import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h" The Swift files in your target will be visible in Objective-C .m files containing this import
>
> statement. For information on using Swift from Objective-C code, see
> Using Swift from Objective-C.