# Instantiating a Swift ViewController in an Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I've imported a Swift `UIViewController` in an Objective-C-based project and I've followed

- [Apple's guide to using Swift Classes in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_78)

and

- [This useful step-by-step Swift integration for Xcode Objc-based projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27251979/4475605)

My project doesn't crash, but I can't get a view to load. I'm attempting to instantiate a `viewController`, but it shows up as a white blank screen:

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mySwiftVC"];
```

I put a breakpoint in immediately after the prior line and `po rootViewController` gives a memory address.

I threw a `println` in the `viewDidLoad` of `MySwiftVC`, but nothing comes up. All the lights "are on", but nothing displays/executes. Any ideas where to look for resolution?

Here's the method where the prior line was called:

```
- (void)checkDisclaimer {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"disclaimerAcknowledged"]boolValue] == NO) {
        // set to instantiate disclaimer VC
        UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"disclaimer"];
        self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
        NSLog(@"Disclaimer IS NOT acknowledged");
    } else {
// this is the line that's working from a memory standpoint, but nothing happens
        UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"launchScreen"];
        self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
        NSLog(@"Disclaimer IS acknowledged");
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Comment: And how are you presenting the view controller?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. It fills the screen. It worked before, but doesn't work with the `SwiftVC` even though I get a memory address for the `SwiftVC`

Comment: @nhgrif is asking what code do you use to make sure the VC shows on screen

Comment: That code displays an Obj-C VC without a problem. Pointing it at the SwiftVC doesn't work, but it doesn't crash either. Kind of annoying

Comment: I don't remember what I did in that particular project, but it's addressed here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html in the section titled "To import Swift code into Objective-C from the same target". I think I ended up following those steps, cleaning cache, closing project, nuking derived data, and running it again.