# Initializing UIView's frame with CGRectZero

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, translate

I found a tutorial on how to do something that's written in `Swift`. I'm at the tail end of an `Objective-C` project and I've tried importing the classes into `Objective-C`, but [that's been a bug-riddled, time monopolizing disaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590419/instantiating-a-swift-viewcontroller-in-an-objective-c-project), so I'm translating from Swift to Objective-C instead.

I got the `UIView.h/m` to the point where there are no warnings/errors, but adding the view on the `UIViewController` is a different story. I've posted the initialization code I'm trying to "translate" below. I welcome input re: what I'm fouling up.

**Code from Swift class for initializing UIView:**

```
var parentFrame :CGRect = CGRectZero

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = Colors.clear
}
```

**Code from my "translated" Objective-C class for initializing the UIView**

**`myUIView.h`**

```
// At MartinR's suggestion, I removed the pointer here
@property (nonatomic) CGRect parentFrame;
```

**`myUIView.m`**

```
// No compiler errors -- the errors occur on the UIViewController
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:(self.parentFrame)];
    self.parentFrame = CGRectZero;
    if (self) {
        [super setFrame:self.parentFrame];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to add the UIView to the UIViewController. I can't figure out why I'm getting a warning below:

**Swift UIViewController code to add the UIView**

```
  func addHolderView() {
    let boxSize: CGFloat = 75.0
    holderView.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.width / 2 - boxSize / 2,
                              y: view.bounds.height / 2 - boxSize / 2,
                              width: boxSize,
                              height: boxSize)
    holderView.parentFrame = view.frame
    holderView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(holderView)
    holderView.addOval()
  }
```

**My "translated" Objective-C ViewController riddled with implementation errors**

**`myUIViewController.h`**

```
#import "HolderView.h"

// blah blah

@property (nonatomic, strong) HolderView *holderView;
```

**`myUIViewController.m`**

```
- (void)addHolderView {
    CGFloat boxSize = 75.0;
// WARNING: The following line says "expression result unused"
    [self.holderView initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_view.bounds.size.width / 2 - boxSize / 2,
                                              _view.bounds.size.height / 2 - boxSize / 2,
                                              boxSize,
                                              boxSize)];
    // Warning here went away by removing the pointer on CGRect parentFrame
    self.holderView.parentFrame = view.frame;
    self.holderView.delegate = self; // I have the delegate stuff squared away
    [self.view addSubview:self.holderView];
}
```

Thank you for reading.

**Updated to reflect input from MartinR in comments.**

I updated the code above to remove a pointer on `CGRect parentFrame`.

Comment: Once you have realized that `parentFrame` should **not be a pointer** you can clean up your code considerably :)

Comment: Thank you @MartinR! I'm venturing outside of my Interface Builder "comfort zone" here. I've spent more time than I care to admit on this. If you've got more to add, I'm all ears.

Comment: `@property (nonatomic) CGRect parentFrame;` without the `*`. (Do you know what a pointer is?). Then clean up your `initWithFrame` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift version of `addHolderView` is using a `holderView` that already exists and updating it.  Yours is either trying to re-init something that exists or else init something that hasn't been allocated.  It's hard to know which, but either one is a bad idea.

To mimic the original code, just assign a new frame size without an init.  To be sure of what's going on, check that `self.holderView` points to a valid object using the debugger or a `NSLog` statement.

Comment: Thank you! I'll tinker with it this morning. Once I get this initialization out of the way, everything else I'm "translating" is straightforward. It's frustrating to be stuck on the first step, but knowing everything afterwards ;)

Comment: Finally got it. Had 2 problems--1) Wasn't instantiating the UIViewController and 2) I was trying to do too much in the initializer--I set the frame dimensions locally on the UIViewController rather than the class.