# Cannot use RAMAnimatedTabBarController in Objective-C project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

In my Obj-C project, I wanted to use RAMAnimatedTabBarController(https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar) which is a Swift module for adding animation to tabbar items. 
I configured all the settings according to [Can't use Swift classes inside Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c) and I imported the Swift bridging header using

`#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"`

The header file was generated successfully but when I tried to create a RAMAnimatedTabBarController instance
`RAMAnimatedTabBarController *test`
XCode still gives the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'RAMAnimatedTabBarItem'". Can someone help with this?

Comment: For Obj-C users https://github.com/polobymulberry/animated-tab-bar-Objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the swift code with cocoapods and used 
`@import RAMAnimatedTabBarController;`
at the beginning of the file I was using