# Can't find Swift AppDelegate inside Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to call my Swift AppDelegate inside my Objective-C AppDelegate.
I've created the Bridging header and the header file "myProjectName-Swift.h"

The error is:
**Unknown type name "NatDelegate" did you mean "NRAppDelegate"**

**My Objective-C AppDelegate "NRAppDelegate.mm:**

```
#import "NRAppDelegate.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UnityAppController.h"
#import "UI/UnityView.h"
#import "UI/UnityViewControllerBase.h"
#import "VuforiaRenderDelegate.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import <sys/utsname.h>
#import <channels-Swift.h>

// Unity native rendering callback plugin mechanism is only supported
// from version 4.5 onwards
#if UNITY_VERSION>434
// Exported methods for native rendering callback
//extern "C" void UnitySetGraphicsDevice(void* device, int deviceType, int eventType);
//extern "C" void UnityRenderEvent(int marker);
extern "C" void VuforiaRenderEvent(int marker);
#endif

@implementation NRAppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{


    NatAppDelegate *delegate = [NatAppDelegate sharedInstance]; //Error it's here!!
    bool launchBool;
    launchBool = [delegate application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    launchBool = [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    //return launchBool;*/
    return launchBool;

     }

@end

IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS(NRAppDelegate)
```

**My NRAppDelegate.h :**

```
#import "UnityAppController.h"

@interface NRAppDelegate : UnityAppController<UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL orientationIsLocked;

@end
```

**My NatAppDelegate.swift:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

//@UIApplicationMain
class NatAppDelegate : UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    //MARK: Singleton & Constructors
    class var sharedInstance :NatAppDelegate {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = NatAppDelegate()
        }

        return Singleton.instance
    }


    override init() {
        super.init()
    }


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


        NRChannelsManager.sharedInstance().loadChannelsList();

               return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning(application: UIApplication) {

        NSLog("Application received a memory warning. Sending to NR")

    }

}
```

**My Bridging Header and Swift header file:**

[image]

**I also checked:**

- Product Module Name : channels
- Defines Module : YES
- Embedded Content Contains Swift : YES
- Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : YES

**I've read all kinds of theories and advices but no effort i.e:**
[Can't use Swift classes inside Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c)

**Any help will be appreciated :)**

**PS:** I notice a strange behavior when i click in the first NatAppDelegate it goes to the "NRAppDelegate.h" when i click i the second "NatAppDelegate" it goes to the swift class.

NatAppDelegate *<-(Click here i go to the NRAppDelegate.h)* *delegate = [NatAppDelegate *<-(Click here and i go to the swift)* sharedInstance];

Comment: Why do you have two app delegates...?

Comment: You can create thousands of classes implementing UIApplicationDelegate but only one of them can be THE application's delegate at a time.

Comment: because its an integration of a unity project in native code.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, @firetrap...

Comment: The unity/vuforia has her own AppDelegate wich our NRAppDelegate will override and redirect to the swift delegate starting the native code. The unity integration it's not easy we know but in my case it's necessary. The app life cycle in this cases it's different from a normal project: when your start the app it will start unity and unity will be on pause but instantiated, so the native will run, when the user press the viewController it will put unity in resume and unity will run

Answer (score 1):

Add the `@objc` attribute to `class NatAppDelegate` .

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

> A Swift class or protocol must be marked with the @objc attribute to
>   be accessible and usable in Objective-C. This attribute tells the
>   compiler that this piece of Swift code can be accessed from
>   Objective-C.