# Using Swift class in Objective C class with swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, import, bridging-header

My project is a `Swift` project, which contains custom class in `Objective C`. Now I'm trying to use an another custom class which is in Swift in my `Objective C` class. I'm able to get the class, but all it's methods are **not** accessible.

Project : Swift

Custom Library : Swift

Want to use in : Objective C (another custom library)

All the methods are public in that custom class, but still I'm unable to access it. I had also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27251979/2594560). Please guide me

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can't help because I never did this  , but [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122) may help.

Comment: Can you see your methods inside your myproject-Swift.h ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use Swift classes inside Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c)

Comment: @nielsbot it's different. I'm making the edit

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can use when u are drag and drop the objective class then one bridge file is created and this file import the objective c class .h file like import "test.h"

Comment: Thanks for you'r reply. Bridging file is included included, because of which I'm able to use that custom Objective C class. I want to include Custom Swift class in that Objective C class. Please check my question again

Comment: You need to import ProjectName-Swift.h. Note that it's the project name - the other answers make the mistake of using the class name.

This single file is an autogenerated header that defines Objective-C interfaces for all Swift classes in your project that are either annotated @objc or inherit from NSObject.

Comment: I had done that only for importing Swift to Objective C. I can get the class, but I'm unable to use it's methods