# Using Swift in Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, swift, interop

Although I have followed and tried everything from [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c) and read all of Apple's Guide of Swift-ObjC interoperability, I'm unable to recognize or use Swift fies in my project.

I have created a Swift file that declares/defines a class called `TorusView` that inherits from UIView.  I've tried to gain access to this class in another class `MenuView` by importing the bridging header, importing the Swift class, importing the class with the syntax `*-swift.h` (which seems to now be `*.swift.h`in Xcode7.2).  I've made all of the modifications to my target build settings recommended in that lengthy Stack question and a variety of others from google searches.

Nothing I've tried has allowed me to create a `TorusView` objective in my objective-C class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import a header file `YourAppName-Swift.h`, it contains all the public (and internal if same target) declared types in Swift.

Comment: Does the public interface of your Swift class include anything not supported in ObjC, like generics or Swift enums?

Comment: No it is just an empty class that inherits from UIView

Comment: Have you run the app to make sure the header is generated?

Comment: Now I am getting errors all throughout my swift file on every line.  Xcode is forcing me to add semi-Colons after my import statements.

Comment: I ran/built the app many times.  (I originally accidentally lost my target and created a new one, so now my project name appears to be DraWave_Iphone_Target)..

There is a file in my main bundle folder called `DraWave_Iphone_Target-Bridging-Header.h`  and I've checked my derived data dir  and buried in there is a file `DerivedSources/buildDraWave_Iphone_Target-Swift`

Comment: I've gone through and changed all the recommended build settings such as `define Modules` at the project and target levels.  I've tried all permutations and included all variations of these files.  Nothing has worked.  It even looks like the Apple documentation on Obj-C/Swift mix and match is out of date with what my xcode is doing.

Answer (score 0):

first: Build Settings --> defines module --> YES.

second:Product Module Name -->YOUR project NAME.

last：improt "YOUR project NAME-Swift.h" in your Object-c file

like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWOyr.jpg)