# how to through swift access property which be defined by objC

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native

I'm newbie that learning swift, and I try to define property in objC souce, but then I have no idea that access it from my swift code :(

**foo.h**

```
#import "RCTView.h"


@interface Foo : RCTView

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *config;

@end
```

**foo.m**

```
#import "foo.h"
#import "RCTViewManager.h"
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"


@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(Foo, RCTViewManager)

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(config, NSString);

@end
```

**foo.swift**

```
import Foundation


@objc(Foo)
class Foo :  {

struct Foo
  {
    static var bar = ""
  }

  func setConfig(config: String!) {
    Foo.bar = config
  }

}
```

now I just through struct to get property `config` value, how could I get it directly from swift code?

thanks for your time.

Comment: you need to add a swift bridging header

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **swift** and **objective-c** in the same project, then you have to use a **bridging header** which connects swift to objective-c. Here is the official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

This question should help you: [Can't use Swift classes inside Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I already add bridging-header file in my project :)