# Embedded Content Contains Swift Code with Xcode 8 Beta

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, compilation

I am developing a command line macOS application(with Objective-C) which uses other 3rd party Swift libraries. I am retrieving an error says
"`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib`"

Previous answers recommend to set "**Embedded Content Contains Swift Code**" flag to true. However, this flag is missing with Xcode 8 beta.

I have tried "`ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`", which i believe a new flag for Xcode 8. It doesn't work either :(

Is anyone tried to compile and execute a command line application with Xcode 8 beta that is;
- developed using Objective-C
- having 3rd party swift library dependencies

**Update:**

I ended up copying everything under "**/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx**" into the folder where the executable stands. Not a perfect solution but it works.

Answer (score 27):

Check this mentioned in Xcode 8 beta 2 Release Notes:

> The new build setting ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES replaces the use of EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT. This setting indicates that Xcode should always embed Swift standard libraries in a target for which it has been set, whether or not the target contains Swift code. A typical scenario for using this setting is when a target directly uses or embeds another product which contains Swift code.

*Note: EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT has been deprecated. (26158130).*

Comment: I have the exact same situation as the OP, and when I set the newly recommended flag, I get the warning "Not running swift-stdlib-tool: ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES is enabled, but the product type 'Command-line Tool' is not a wrapper type."  Anyone else see this and know how to get around it?  (XCode 8A218a) Swift 3.0

Comment: So do we assume that  EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT is effectively always on nowadays? 

The function of that other switch doesn't seem equivalent.

Comment: but `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` set to true, do not copy the `libswiftAVFoundation.dylib` to the target.