# Importing TZStackView in an objective - c project

Tags: ios, objective-c, tzstackview

I am trying to use TZStackView due to limitations of UIStackView but since it's written in swift, I can't add it to my project which is Objective-c project.
 I've added swift class to objective-c projects before but this doesn't seem to work.
 I've copied TZStackView files to my project directory and got like hundreds of error messages.
 How do I use it ( I don't wanna use pods)?

Comment: Please provide the xcode version your using??

Comment: @Jeyamahesan i am using xcode 7.1.1

Comment: check this solution. follow the steps, sure it will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/27251979/6176024

Comment: xcode 8 is more simpler than the above solution. if your going to use xcode 8 then you need to convert the syntax to swift 3.Thats all.no errors!!! no warnings!!!

Comment: @Jeyamahesan well it's really not about adding a header but I can't even compile code after adding it to my project. I got 106 errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [TZStackView v1.2.0](https://github.com/tomvanzummeren/TZStackView/releases/tag/1.2.0), [TZStackView v1.3.0](https://github.com/tomvanzummeren/TZStackView/releases/tag/1.3.0) supports swift 3 it will works only in xcode8. for xcode7 use [TZStackView v1.2.0](https://github.com/tomvanzummeren/TZStackView/releases/tag/1.2.0).

Comment: This did help. But I am still getting 3 errors after importing TZStackView files to the project. On the line : UIView.setAnimationDidStopSelector(#selector(TZStackView.hiddenAnimationStopped))

Comment: Expected expression in list of expressions

Comment: and one more: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. may be the errors are due to the compatibility with swift. as you mentioned that your using Xcode 7.1.1 which is older for swift, because there are many updates have been made in swift. so my kind advice is to update the Xcode to 7.3.1. Currently i'm using the Xcode 7.3.1 with TZStackView there is no errors and warnings and works like a charm.  If you're satisfied with my answer please upvote and accept my answer.Thank you.