# Is it possible to write iPhone app in both objective c and swift

Tags: ios, iphone

My existing iOS app is in objective c language and i want to add more functionality in my app and i want to do that code in swift language.
So is it possible to create an app which contains both the languages(i.e. in objective c & swift) and Is my app will work fine?

Comment: You can, but it would be easier and cleaner to stick with only one language. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: yes, your app will be fine, you can combine the two languages together; standard procedure during maintaining your app and gradually updating the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In short answer, Yes.

If you have existing project written in objective-c then you can add new classes written in swift. You still have choice if you want to use swift 3.0 ot swift 2.0.
You have to use bridge class in order to achieve that. You will get more guide on Link provided on Apple website.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

However going forward it would make sense that you spend more time on Learning Swift as Apple is now leaning towards Swift 3.0.

[Here is link quick guide.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27251979/2618600)