# Combinating Swift & Objective C files

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a bit complicated classes in swift and Objective-C combinated together:

## Keypad.h:

```
#import "MyApp-Swift.h" 

@interface Keypad : UIViewController {
   ...
   SwiftViewController *swiftViewController; // this is written in swift
   ...
}
```

This worked well.

Then I created a new swift file:

## AnotherSwiftViewController.swift

```
 @objc class AnotherSwiftViewController: UITableViewController {
    func myMethod() {
      let keypad = appDelegate.getTabs().selectedViewController as! Keypad // I need get ObjC Keypad class
    }
}
```

And I need to use there the ObjcC Keypad class.

So I added it to the MyApp-Bridging-Header.h:

## MyApp-Bridging-Header.h

```
...
// lot of other Obj-C files imported
...
#import "Keypad.h"
...
```

And I get the error:

```
> .../MyApp-Bridging-Header.h:31:9: note: in file included from .../MyApp-Bridging-Header.h:31: #import "Keypad.h"

> .../Keypad.h:13:9: error: 'My_App-Swift.h' file not found \#import "My_App-Swift.h"

> <unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '.../MyApp-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Any ideas?

/// EDIT:

Maybe will help:

I'm using

```
#import "My_App-Swift.h"
```

In the `Keypad.h` file, not in standard `Keypad.m`, because I have there that **SwiftViewController *swiftViewController;** property

Maybe it will help

Comment: Full example to use obj-c and swift together: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41068740/4488252

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help - there is not described problem which I have - calling use ObjcC in Swift which using another Swift as class variable

Answer (score 0):

You have a good point in your ///Edit.

In `Keypad.h` remove `#import "MyApp-Swift.h"` and add a forward declaration of your Swift class as follows:

```
...
@class SwiftViewController;
@interface Keypad : UIViewController {
...
```

This should do it assuming `Keytab.h` references `SwiftViewController` only by pointer and your bridging header is imported correctly otherwise.

See section Referencing a Swift Class or Protocol in an Objective-C Header in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html.