# using Swift code in Objective-C project by creating bridge files in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

while merging swift code to objective c existing projective c project am not able to import the header files into bridge file and also i get some syntax errors in the merged swift classes [am getting following errors what has showed in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldx99.png)

Comment: Have you checked this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Do you create Bridging Header from these steps.

Step1. Create Bridging Header file

[image]

Step 2. After creating bridging header goto Project Settings and search Objective-C bridging header and add bridging header file path.

[image]

By following these step you have successfully added bridging header file. Next you have to import framework, you like to add.
If you still found any issue then show us the error.