# Swift Project With Objective C Wrapper OpenCV

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, opencv, cocoapods

I have just started to use the openCV library and I am trying to get everything set up. I have a swift project and have dowloaded the framework through cocoa pods. I am trying to import the openCV framework in my objective-c file and I keep getting errors. This is my code and the following are the errors.

```
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"

//this line causes the errors
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


@implementation OpenCVWrapper
@end
```

Errors:

[image]

Comment: Just import openCV .h files in Bridging-Header.h, it doesn't work?

Comment: Please check edit. I have already done what you have said and am trying to use the openCV functionality in my objective-c class.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c, hope it will helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little digging, I finally found the solution:

Import any Apple headers **AFTER** those of OpenCV. So the code should look like this:

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Bridging Header file and import the objective c file in it. after creating a file you need to add the path of this file into Build settings of project Target. Find Bridging Header in build settings. please refer

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: Please check edit. I have already done what you have said and am trying to use the openCV functionality in my objective-c class.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem. I solved it by just changing my
**Helper.m**
file to
**Helper.mm**