# In file included warnings in Xcode (Objective-C project)

Tags: ios, xcode

I have got many warnings like: `In file included from ...`

[image]
[image]
[image]

you can see it from different issues but the same problem in "fi file included ", I think it means I reimport the .h file ?

here is when I click in to the error file:
[image]

and I have no idea what does it means. and there are 100s of warnings like that in my project.

Comment: These are warnings, not errors.

Comment: what you did before that? Did you import any files or what action you perfomr.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS , i import some swift file in my project , than the error shows up.

Comment: ohk..did yoy add a bridging header file in your project.  Look in these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: thank you , I have import the bridging header. and my swift file works fine. I just want remove those annoying warnings , it makes the compile speed very slow

Comment: did you tried to change the compiler settings for warning under section Apple LLVM 8.1 - Warning in the Build settings of your project?

Comment: @Lorenzo no, i haven't try that, can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

set target setings CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS=NO