# Use Swift classes in Bridging Objective C files

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, objective-c++

I have project which is written on Swift but some part of project is written on Objective-C++ for integration with C++ library. My .mm files don't see Swift classes. I have done all steps from [Can't use Swift classes inside Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c) but still can't fix it. Auto-generated `"project-Swift.h"` generates with errors. I've tried to delete pieces of code in which error occurred and it worked well, but this `"project-Swift.h"` regenerates every time when I clean the project. Here is screenshot with errors [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrLwr.jpg). Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're missing `@import "AppKit.h"`. Have you included `import AppKit` in the Swift code? Alternately, you've created a circular dependency. Do you have an ObjC header file that imports `project-Swift.h` and is itself included in the bridging header? That's not legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you're not including the headers that define the missing symbols, like `NSViewController`, before including your bridging header.

Comment: Sorry for maybe stupid question, but, what you mean by "before including your bridging header."? Where I should include that?

Comment: Add the missing include/import Statement directly above your current `#import "project-Swift.h"` line.