# Bridging header in objective C - Unexpected '@' in program

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I'm trying to use some of my `swift` classes inside of my `Objective C` project.
Before to do it, I have validated the ios versions.ç

I'm using 
[Can't use Swift classes inside Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c)

but, at the moment to update the `MyProject-Bridging-Header.h` with:

```
@import Foundation;


@objc public class myClass
```

I get the error:

> Unexpected '@' in program Expected ';' after top level declarator

How can I fix this error to import my `swift` classes?

Comment: leave the bridge file empty , read all the steps in the link you shared carefully

Comment: Why did you write Swift code in an Objective-C header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to import swift classes say like  (suppose in file named **MySwift.swift** to be dragged to the project)

```
@objc public class MyClass:NSObject {

}
```

inside an objective-c project , you shouldn't but it inside the bridge .h file but to only import this line

```
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

top of the .m file you use the class in